# Is the Curl $\nabla \times$ symmetric under inner product？

Tags: vector-analysis, mathematical-physics

If $\nabla\cdot u=0,$ and $\nabla \times(\nabla \times u)=\nabla(\nabla \cdot u)-\nabla^2 u,$ we know that $-\Delta u=\nabla \times(\nabla \times u).$ But I have a question, why
$$(-\Delta u,v)_{L^2}=(\nabla \times u,\nabla \times v)_{L^2}?$$
Is the Curl $\nabla \times$ symmetric under inner product？

Comment: I think this should follow from musical isomorphism if you write it out in forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes from the divergence of the cross product identity in the following way:
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla\cdot[v\times (\nabla\times u)] &=& (\nabla\times v)\cdot(\nabla\times u) -v\cdot[\nabla\times(\nabla\times u)] \\&=& (\nabla\times v)\cdot(\nabla\times u) + v\cdot\Delta u-v\cdot\nabla(\nabla\cdot u)
\end{eqnarray}
Integrating over all space makes the LHS vanish by the divergence theorem and $\nabla\cdot u$ vanishes by assumption, leaving
$$
(\Delta u, v) + (\nabla\times u, \nabla\times v) = 0
$$
and the result follows.